# Validation rule using regex

Tags: regex, pcre

Regex validation can receive next samples of strings:

```
t/E/s/t
t/E/s/t/
t/E/s/t/////...
t/E/s/t/////?page=10
t/E/s/t/////?page=10/
t/E/s/t/////?page=10////...
```

I need to split the string to the parts:

```
1. t/E/s/t
2. ?page=10////...
```

- [the dots mean that "/" symbol can be repeated many times]. If "?..." part does not exist the second result string should be empty.

I have wrote the regex: `^(.*[^\/])\/+(\?.*)$`
The problem that it does not work if the text string does not contain part of "?page=10///...". To make valid verification for string without "?page..." part i need second validation string: `^(.*[^\/])\/+$`

I want to have only one validation rule.

Any ideas how to combine them?

Comment: Should `t/E/s/t/` return `t/E/s/t/` or `t/E/s/t`? What should `t/E/s/t/////...` return?

Comment: You can try to make the last group optional `(\?.*)?`

Comment: i have tried (.*[^/])/+([?].*)? but in such case does not split the string to the two parts.

Comment: Is this solved, or are you still struggling with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice if something like `/(.*[^\/])\/*(\?.*)?/` worked. But the problem is that the regex engine will find the best possible match for `(.*[^\/])\/*`, even if this means matching `(\?.*)?` against the empty string.*

You could do the following:

```
/(.*[^\/])\/*(\?.*)|(.*[^\/])/
```

This is slightly unsatisfactory in that you get 3 capture groups even though you only wanted 2. So you could do this instead, if (the version of) the language you're using allows the `(?|...)` construct:

```
/(?|(.*[^\/])\/*(\?.*)|(.*[^\/]))/
```

*More generally, suppose the regex engine is faced with a regex `/AB/`. The match it returns will contain the best possible match for `/A/` (by which I mean the best match that can actually be extended to a match for `/AB/`). To put it another way, it doesn't backtrack into `A` until it's finished searching for matches for `B`.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick side note, I used `~` instead of `/` for delimiters so your `/` don't need to be escaped.  Also, I used a character class for the question mark (`[?]`) instead of having to escape it (`\?`)...this is just personal preference for readability.

First we capture the literal string `t/E/s/t`.  Then we match 0+ `/`s (if there **needs** to be a `/` in between `t/E/s/t` and `?`, then change the `*` to `+` for 1+).  Finally we capture the question mark followed by the rest of the line (`[?].*`).  This is made optional with the trailing `?`, so that if your string does not have the `?page=10` it will still be matched with an empty second capture.

```
~(t/E/s/t)/*([?].*)?~
```

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/kT4pI3)

Comment: t/E/s/t was only example, the string can be whatever... like "df/wer/ewrwer/"

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<?php
$strings = array(
"t/E/s/t", 
"t/E/s/t/",
"t/E/s/t/////...",
"t/E/s/t/////?page=10",
"t/E/s/t/////?page=10/",
"t/E/s/t/////?page=10////...");
$regex ='~(?<=t/E/s/t)/+~';
foreach($strings as $str) {
    print_r(preg_split($regex,$str));
    echo "<br />";
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => t/E/s/t )
Array ( [0] => t/E/s/t [1] => )
Array ( [0] => t/E/s/t [1] => ... )
Array ( [0] => t/E/s/t [1] => ?page=10 )
Array ( [0] => t/E/s/t [1] => ?page=10/ )
Array ( [0] => t/E/s/t [1] => ?page=10////... )
```

Comment: @DavidKnipe Yes. The question is tagged PCRE, which PHP uses for regex. Unless I missed something that seems like a good tool for the OP.

Comment: PCRE isn't a PHP thing, it covers many other languages too. See the mouseover text for the pcre tag.

Comment: @DavidKnipe I am well aware of the various contexts in which PCRE are used. I compile each new version manually! What gives you the impression that I believe that PCRE is "a PHP thing"? As my reply to you states, PHP uses PCRE for regex, and that seemed like a good tool for the OP.